# Javascript make circle hit canvas borders properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm currently working on a little game but I can't get the circle to hit the left and top canvas border properly. It hits the right and the bottom side correctly.

The circle can be moved with W A S D and must hit all borders of the canvas properly

This is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/tumy8kbh/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JS Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1200" height="800"></canvas>

<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var dx = 2;
    var dy = -2;
    var playerRadius = 80;
    var playerX = (canvas.width-playerRadius)/2;
    var playerY = (canvas.height-playerRadius);
    var rightPressed = false;
    var leftPressed = false;
    var upPressed = false;
    var downPressed = false;

    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

    function keyDownHandler(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 87) {
            upPressed = true;
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 83) {
            downPressed = true;
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 68) {
            rightPressed = true;
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 65) {
            leftPressed = true;
        }
    }
    function keyUpHandler(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 87) {
            upPressed = false;
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 83) {
            downPressed = false;
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 68) {
            rightPressed = false;
        }
        else if(e.keyCode == 65) {
            leftPressed = false;
        }
    }

    function drawPlayer(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(playerX, playerY, playerRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        drawPlayer();

        if(rightPressed && playerX < canvas.width-playerRadius) {
            playerX += 7;
        }
        else if(leftPressed && (playerX - playerRadius) > 0) {
            playerX -= 7;
        }
        else if(upPressed && (playerY - playerRadius) > 0) {
            playerY -= 7;
        }
        else if(downPressed && playerY < canvas.height-playerRadius) {
            playerY += 7;
        }

        if(playerX >= canvas.width){
            leftPressed = false;
        }
    }

    setInterval(draw, 10);

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

If you need some more info please say so.

Comment: it has to do with the way you check if the ball can move. you check if X - radius > 0, then move left by 7. if the ball is 1 pixel away from the left edge, it can move, but it will end up 6 pixels off to the left. after calculating the new X position, check again that X - radius isn't LESS than 0 ... adjust X accordingly ... you'll need to do the same for all directions (bottom and right will stop working if you fix top and left and move to top/left then bottom right

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it right away!

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code: even though you figured it out from the comment

```
function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawPlayer();

    if(rightPressed && playerX < canvas.width-playerRadius) {
        playerX += 7;
        if (playerX > canvas.width-playerRadius) {
            playerX = canvas.width-playerRadius;
        }
    }
    else if(leftPressed && (playerX - playerRadius) > 0) {
        playerX -= 7;
        if (playerX - playerRadius < 0) {
            playerX = playerRadius;
        }
    }
    else if(upPressed && (playerY - playerRadius) > 0) {
        playerY -= 7;
        if (playerY - playerRadius < 0) {
            playerY = playerRadius;
        }
    }
    else if(downPressed && playerY < canvas.height-playerRadius) {
        playerY += 7;
        if (playerY > canvas.height-playerRadius) {
            playerY = canvas.height-playerRadius;
        }
    }
}
```

This is not the most efficient way of dealing with it, but it shows the problem and how to fix it (I think)

There **may** be slight inaccuracies (you may need to +/- 1 in some of the "fixups" - I didn't check properly

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the way you check if the ball can move. you check if X - radius > 0, then move left by 7. if the ball is 1 pixel away from the left edge, it can move, but it will end up 6 pixels off to the left. after calculating the new X position, check again that X - radius isn't LESS than 0 ... adjust X accordingly ... you'll need to do the same for all directions (bottom and right will stop working if you fix top and left and move to top/left then bottom right – **Jaromanda X**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a setInterval with true and false vars for this type of task, you could refresh the scene in every keydown event. I've modified your code, here you have:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var playerRadius = 80;
var playerX = (canvas.width - playerRadius) / 2;
var playerY = (canvas.height - playerRadius);

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);

var moves = {
  87: {x: 0, y: -7},
  83: {x: 0, y: 7},
  68: {x: 7, y: 0},
  65: {x: -7, y: 0}
};

function keyDownHandler(e) {

  if( moves.hasOwnProperty(e.keyCode) ) {

    playerX += moves[e.keyCode].x;
    playerY += moves[e.keyCode].y;

    if(playerX < playerRadius) playerX = playerRadius;
    if(playerX > canvas.width - playerRadius) playerX = canvas.width - playerRadius;
    if(playerY < playerRadius) playerY = playerRadius;
    if(playerY > canvas.height - playerRadius) playerY = canvas.height - playerRadius;

    drawPlayer();

  }

}

function drawPlayer(){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(playerX, playerY, playerRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

drawPlayer();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/tumy8kbh/2/)

Comment: I see what you are doing, but if you use setInterval and true and false vars it runs way smoother. Before I had the true and false vars I used what you just showed us. Thanks though!